# API to read multiple sensor measurements via Orion+keyrock or connect Sth-comet+keyrock?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I am a hardware developer and I have multiple sensors communicating with the framework. I also have deployed the system until cygnus and keyrock components. Currently I have also developed a client that mines time series data straight from connecting on the mongo database. I know this is a crude way of doing things and if I want to play with roles and permissions I have to do it through Orion. The only way you provide for us to read sensor data via Orion is reading the last measurement with this command:

```
curl -G -X GET \ 'http://localhost:1026/v2/entities/urn:ngsi-ld:Motion:001' \ -d 'type=Motion' \ -H 'fiware-service: openiot' \ -H 'fiware-servicepath: /'
```

Is there a way to mine time series data between dates (or N measurements back from now) via orion so i can secure time series data mining and assign it to a role with permission?

I know there is STH-Comet to read time series data but from reading the tutorials I understand that cannot connect sth-comet with keyrock via a proxy. Is this possible?

Comment: I think `-d` is not needed. That GET request doesn't use any payload

Answer (score 0):

As you said, STH is the component you should use for time series information. Basically:

- You send your sensor data to Orion Context Broker (where the last value is accessible using the [NGSIv2 interface](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/stable/), e.g. using a GET operation like the one you show)
- Orion Context Broker sends the data to STH using a notification (based in a pre-existing subscription you need to create in Orion Context Broker using the NGSIv2 interface).

  - For high load scenarios the recommended setup is Orion->Cygnus->STH ([Cygnus](https://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) configured with [NGSISTHSink](https://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cygnus-ngsi/flume_extensions_catalogue/ngsi_sth_sink/index.html) and [NGSIMongoSink](https://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cygnus-ngsi/flume_extensions_catalogue/ngsi_mongo_sink/index.html)) as it performs better that STH to do aggregations.
- You can use the STH [raw API](https://fiware-sth-comet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/raw-data-retrieval/index.html) or [aggregated API](https://fiware-sth-comet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aggregated-data-retrieval/index.html) to get time series information.

What I don't understand from your question is *"I understand that cannot connect sth-comet with keyrock via a proxy"*. Could your edit your question post to elaborate a little bit on it, please?